# Genymotion - /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6: undefined symbol: xcb_wait_for_reply64

Tags: android, x11, genymotion

I installed Genymotion on openSUSE Leap 42.1 and don't have success to execute.
I'm getting the following error:

```
genymotion/genymotion: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6: undefined symbol: xcb_wait_for_reply64
```

I have no idea what may have caused the problem. Anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To solve this problem, navigate to extracted folder (/opt/genymobile/genymotion in my case) and remove the **libxcb.so.1** file.

Comment: But, i fell that remove these lib file makes genymotion more slow.

Comment: any idea, why suddenly this error pops up? like till yesterday it was good now it showing error?

Comment: I've nedded remove the **libdrm.so.2** too.

Comment: Worked for me too

Answer (score 7):

In my case i had to remove to files: libxcb.so.1 and libdrm.so.2. I'm using Kali Rolling.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm using Debian Stretch, I had to remove from the *genymotion* directory the following files: **libxcb.so.1** and **libdrm.so.2**.