# Genymotion - ./genymotion: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libGL.so.1: undefined symbol: drmFreeDevice

Tags: android, genymotion

I've just installed Genymotion on Solus Linux OS.

1st issue was solved by: [Genymotion - /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6: undefined symbol: xcb_wait_for_reply64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39316164/genymotion-usr-lib64-libx11-so-6-undefined-symbol-xcb-wait-for-reply64)
and now I've encountered this one.

Anyone has any idea about this or seen this before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've removed the **libdrm.so.2** file from the install location and now Genymotion is staring.

Comment: First, I've renamed the *libxcb.so.1*. After this I've renamed the *libdrm.so.2*.

Answer (score 1):

I used this command and it works

`rm  -rf libxcb.so.1`

Source: https://arief-jr.blogspot.ie/2016/11/fixed-genaymotion-symbol-lookup-error.html